# How to detect unlock on Android? (AIR App)

Tags: android, flash, events, air

I'm looking for a solution on how to detect when a user unlock the screen to resume an app after the device was in idle. I need an as3 solution since my app is running with AIR.

Answer (score 0):

```
import flash.desktop.NativeApplication;

import flash.desktop.SystemIdleMode;

stage.addEventListener(Event.DEACTIVATE, onLeave);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE, onComeBack);


function onLeave(event:Event):void{
    SoundMixer.stopAll();
    stop();
    NativeApplication.nativeApplication.systemIdleMode = SystemIdleMode.NORMAL;
}


function onComeBack(event:Event):void{
    NativeApplication.nativeApplication.systemIdleMode = SystemIdleMode.KEEP_AWAKE;
    gotoAndPlay("1","Main");
}
```